# Rest Assured API difference b/t param() and queryParam()

Tags: rest, api, automation, automated-tests

I am using Rest Assured API Automation framework for API Testing and can anyone tell me difference between the methods **param()** and **queryParam()** which we use in get() and POSt() request.

Comment: I haven't used Rest Assured, but typically query params are the params received in the query (after ?), and only params, probably will be used for body params in the POST requests (GET typically don't have body)

Comment: Thanks... @DavidVicente

https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#parameters

I just checked the documentation..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RESTassured request parameters can be either query parameters or form parameters.

If you don't specify which, RESTassured will assume GET params are query params and POST params are form params, e.g.

```java
given()
    .spec(spec)
    .param("active", "True")
    .when()
    .post("save")
    .then()
    .statusCode(200);
```

will send form parameters in the body. If you require query parameters, you must use `.queryParam("active", "true")`